# SparkSQL and explode on DataFrame in Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is there an easy way how use `explode` on array column on SparkSQL `DataFrame`? It's relatively simple in Scala, but this function seems to be unavailable (as mentioned in javadoc) in Java.

An option is to use `SQLContext.sql(...)` and `explode` function inside the query, but I'm looking for a bit better and especially cleaner way. `DataFrame`s are loaded from parquet files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems it is possible to use a combination of `org.apache.spark.sql.functions.explode(Column col)` and `DataFrame.withColumn(String colName, Column col)` to replace the column with the exploded version of it.

Comment: Could you provide some example?

Answer (score 20):

I solved it in this manner: say that you have an array column containing job descriptions named "positions", for each person with "fullName".

Then you get from initial schema :

```
root
|-- fullName: string (nullable = true)
|-- positions: array (nullable = true)
    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
    |    |    |-- companyName: string (nullable = true)
    |    |    |-- title: string (nullable = true)
...
```

to schema:

```
root
 |-- personName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- companyName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- positionTitle: string (nullable = true)
```

by doing:

```
    DataFrame personPositions = persons.select(persons.col("fullName").as("personName"),
          org.apache.spark.sql.functions.explode(persons.col("positions")).as("pos"));

    DataFrame test = personPositions.select(personPositions.col("personName"),
    personPositions.col("pos").getField("companyName").as("companyName"), personPositions.col("pos").getField("title").as("positionTitle"));
```

Comment: in java 8 and Spark 2.4.7 the explode(..) method returns a Column and not a DataFrame. Can you please specify your versions where explode is giving a dataframe to you?

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar problem with a little twist i have the data is ";" separated value , so I have to convert it in array then use explode on it

```
Dataset<Row> modelNum = csv.select("ROWNUM", "MODELNUM");
//converting string data type to array then using explode function to decompose
modelNum = modelNum.withColumn("MODEL", split(modelNum.col("MODELNUM"), ";"));
modelNum = modelNum.select(modelNum.col("ROWNUM"), explode(modelNum.col("MODEL")).alias("MODEL_"));
```

data looks like below before and after explode

```
+------+-------------+    |ROWNUM|MODEL_|
|ROWNUM|     MODELNUM|    +------+------+
+------+-------------+    |     1|1060008|
|     1|1060008;1261290|  |     1|1261290|
|     2|1060008;1261290|  |     2|1060008|
|     3|1060008;1261290|  |     2|1261290|
                          |     3|1060008|
                          |     3|1261290|
```